# jQuery click only working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

This is my site http://projekt.smartunit.de/ipos/faq-downloads-videos, I created "test" button, please scroll down to see them. And this is jQuery:

```
jQuery(".test").click(function(){
    alert("dfndfndfndffd");
});
```

But it only working in Firefox, not working in IE, chrome, safari, opera..

I don't know what did wrong? Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: There are invisible elements in the way of your "test" link, overlapping it and catching your click first.

Comment: @JonUleis Do you know exactly elements?

Answer (score -1):

its issue of overlay. Add these into your .css file

```
.test{
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<span class="test" style="position: absolute;">test</span>
```

Comment: Yeah position: absolute working but it will broken website.

Comment: That is your design issue not jQuery issue. You have to set spacing accordingly after position absolute.